# Combination of BETWEEN and IN clause in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
    SELECT * FROM emp WHERE emp.id 
(BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000) OR IN ('3000','3001','4000')
```

How to write this type of query with combination of BETWEEN and IN clause in Oracle?

Comment: `'3000'` is a string literal not a number. Do not compare apples (numbers) to oranges (strings). Use proper number literals (without single quotes) in the in clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repeat the column name (and don't use strings for numbers):

```
SELECT *
  FROM emp
 WHERE emp.id BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000 OR emp.id IN (3000, 3001, 4000)
```

You might want to bracket the whole OR term if there are other conditions AND'ed with it:

```
SELECT *
  FROM emp
 WHERE (emp.id BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000 OR emp.id IN (3000, 3001, 4000))
   AND ...
```

There is nothing here that is specific to Oracle, either — just for once.  You can apply it to any SQL DBMS.

Comment: You might want to enhance the answer further and use proper number literals in the `IN` clause instead of the string literals.

Comment: True enough...I'll fix.